# Recursively batch-resave Illustrator AI files to legacy format

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing

I need to downsave a few hundred AI files from AI CC to CS6. They are scattered across dozens of folders and I need a way to **recursively *overwrite*** the AI CC files with CS6 compatible files.

I researched and tried a few solutions, but none of them fits the bill.

Optimally this should be a reusable .jsx script, but if there's another way to do this somehow through OS X's Finder (savedSearch), that would be good, too.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

**PS**: Two scripts I found which more or less do what I need. Tried to make a *Frankenscript* out of parts of both, but no success, yet.

[Script one](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4735127#4735127)

[Script two](http://xcorr.net/2010/05/12/batch-export-ai-files-to-pdf/)

Comment: Why won't those scripts work for you and where did you get stuck trying to make them do what you need to do?

Comment: @Joonas They aren't recursive + they don't overwrite the original files. They function properly (batch saving to legacy), but to make this work I'd have to put all .ai files in one folder, which then would be resaved to another folder with absolutely no folder structure. I don't really have an idea how to make the script recursive. I need it to preserve the whole folder structure without touching other files, just resave (overwrite) all .ai files to a legacy format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it wasn't complicated, I decided to write it from scratch. I wouldn't expect the script to be very fast, due to the fact that it's opening, saving and closing files. It should highly depend on your computer and the .ai file(s) in question.

Make sure to check the first two variables: `overwrite` and `targetVersion`, before trying to run the script. You may also want to check the `SaveOptions_ai` function to further adjust the save settings

[image: Illustrator convert to legacy.jsx]

**As always, use at your own risk.** Especially with the overwrite option on, this is extremely destructive script and can render your files unusable, if you save it with low enough file version. 
**If you want to use overwrite, I'd suggest you duplicate the parent folder before running the script.**

```
// Illustrator convert to legacy.jsx
// https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/df2f9e31bdb365a6e5df

// Finds all .ai files from the input folder + its subfolders and converts them to the version given below in a variable called "targetVersion"

// Tested in Illustrator cc 2014 (Mac)
// Didn't bother to do a speed test with my macbook air...

#target illustrator

    // If set to false, a new file will be written next to the original file.
    // The new file will have (legacyFile) in the name.
    // Files with (legacyFile) in the file name are always ignored.
var overwrite = true, // boolean
    // Accepted values:
    // 8, 9, 10, 11 (cs), 12 (cs2), 13 (cs3), 14 (cs4), 15 (cs5), 16 (cs6), 17 (cc)
    targetVersion = 13;

if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {

    alert("ERROR: \n Close all documents before running this script." );

}
// Run the script
else {

    var files,
        folder = Folder.selectDialog("Input folder...");

    // If folder variable return null, user most likely canceled the dialog or
    // the input folder and it subfolders don't contain any .ai files.
    if ( folder != null ) {

        // returns an array of file paths in the selected folder.
        files = GetFiles( folder );

        // This is where things actually start happening...
        process( files );

    }

}


function process( files ) {

    // Loop through the list of .ai files:
    // Open > Save > Close > LOOP
    for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {

        // Current file
        var file = files[i]

        // Open
        app.open( file );

        // If overwrite is false, create a new file, otherwise use "file" variable;
        file = !overwrite ? new File( file.toString().replace(".ai", " (legacyFile).ai") ) : file;

        // Save
        app.activeDocument.saveAs( file, SaveOptions_ai() )

        // Close
        app.activeDocument.close( SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES );

    }

    // For better of for worse...
    alert( "Script is done." );

}

function SaveOptions_ai() {

    var saveOptions = new IllustratorSaveOptions();

    saveOptions.compatibility = Compatibility[ "ILLUSTRATOR" + targetVersion ];
    saveOptions.flattenOutput = OutputFlattening.PRESERVEAPPEARANCE;
    saveOptions.compressed = true; // Version 10 or later
    saveOptions.pdfCompatible = true; // Version 10 or later
    saveOptions.embedICCProfile = true; // Version 9 or later
    saveOptions.embedLinkedFiles = false; // Version 7 or later

    return saveOptions

}

function GetFiles( folder ) {

    var i, item,
        // Array to store the files in...
        files = [],
        // Get files...
        items = folder.getFiles();

    // Loop through all files in the given folder
    for ( i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {

        item = items[i];

        // Find .ai files
        var fileformat = item.name.match(/\.ai$/i),
            legacyFile = item.name.indexOf("(legacyFile)") > 0;

        // If item is a folder, check the folder for files.
        if ( item instanceof Folder ) {

            // Combine existing array with files found in the folder
            files = files.concat( GetFiles( item ) );


        }
        // If the item is a file, push it to the array.
        else if ( item instanceof File && fileformat && !legacyFile ) {

            // Push files to the array
            files.push( item );

        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: Just tested it on two giant folders filled with .ai files and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! However, one small addition: "app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;" at the beginning to make it completely unattended. And Illustrator apparently hangs after closing the "Script is done." alert. Aside from this it's perfect - did the job very well!

Comment: And it's definitely a good idea to make a backup/copy of the parent folder as you suggested, considering how destructive this script is (or could be).

Comment: @Marco Yea, it wouldn't hurt to hide those. The script didn't hang at the last alert in any of my tests. You got any idea what might be causing it? I doubt that it's because something is still running. Can you recreate it?

Comment: Yleinsä ei kirjoteta joka toiselle riville kommentteja. Koska näin ylläpitotoimet tuplautuu, eikä siitä ole hyötyä kun opettaessa.

Comment: @joojaa näin on

Comment: This line `files = files.concat( GetFiles( item ) );` combines existing array with files found in the folder. But what happen if subfolder contains files with the same name as in folder?

Comment: Oh, I understand: file is a full path to file, not only a file name. Excelent.

Comment: @IvanZ, yes. There are kinda two sides to this. One is how `concat` works and the other is how AI works. So, `concat` don't care about duplicates in the first place. It just sticks the second array at the end of the first array no questions asked. But fortunately, since these are arrays with full paths to the files that are later fed to AI, they are treated just like any other file.

Comment: I adapted this script to batch convert ai in folder and subfolders to svg and it works well.

Comment: @IvanZ, cool :) If you want, you could fork it and paste in your code + what it does. I’ve noticed there’s one fork that either converts from ai to eps or from eps to another version (I forgot). Or just post a comment with a link. Or not... choice is yours.

Comment: I have adapted a code from [here](https://gist.github.com/seltzered/4405256); lines 63 & 66; and use this [commnet](https://gist.github.com/seltzered/4405256#gistcomment-2611598)

Answer (score 0):

So I just discovered the concept of Illustrator scripts today and I have no idea how to create or edit one. I tried this one and it did work for me to convert newer ai files to legacy ai files, but I'm wondering if there's a version that would allow you to take a newer eps file and downsave it to an older ai (cs6) file?

Comment: I heard back from the author of the original code with the answer to my question. Changing ai to eps in line 101 answers my question.