# Recursively batch-resave Illustrator svg files with specific options

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, batch-processing, illustrator-scripting

I neew to apply *fit to artwork bounds* and  resave all files and keep file stucture. All my files are svg. and i want to save them with this settings:[image]

The most close solution i found is:
[Recursively batch-resave Illustrator AI files to legacy format](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54930/recursively-batch-resave-illustrator-ai-files-to-legacy-format)

but have no idea how to add an action *fit to artwork bounds* and specify options like on image.

Answer (score 1):

to be able to record "Fit to Artwork Bounds" you have to use "Insert Menu Item..." in the Action's Flyout Menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no way to record 'Fit to Artwork Bounds' in an action... but there is a way to get what you're after without doing that anyway.

**You need to create 2 separate actions using this method.**

So open one of your SVGs (after making a backup copy of your SVG folder for safe keeping) and in the Actions Panel click on 'Create New Action' and hit 'Record':

[image: Action Panel]

**Action 1**

- Go to File > Export > Export As...
- Don't change the filename – just overwrite
- Choose options, click OK
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the document

Now you can press the 'Stop' button at the bottom of the Actions Panel

That saves your SVG 'trimmed' (fit to the artwork bounds).

Now open the file you just exported and click 'Create New Action' again.

**Action 2**

- Go to File > Save As...
- Again overwrite the file
- Choose options as you've specified and click OK:

[image: SVG Options]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close
- Click 'Stop' in the Actions Panel

Now just batch run these actions on your entire SVG folder, in order, one after the other...

Done